# Как настроить L2TP VPN на centos 6.9?

Tags: centos, vpn, l2tp, ppp

Не могу подключиться к vpn серверу. Работаю на CentOS 6.9

Конфиг `/etc/xl2tpd/xl2tpd.conf`:

```
[global]
port = 1701
force userspace = yes

[lns default]
ip range = xxx.xxx.xxx.10-xxx.xxx.xxx.255
local ip = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
refuse chap = yes
refuse pap = yes
require authentication = yes
name=vpn-server
ppp debug = yes
pppoptfile = /etc/ppp/options.xl2tpd
length bit = yes
```

Настройка `/etc/ppp/options.xl2tpd`:

```
require-mschap-v2
ms-dns 8.8.8.8
ms-dns 8.8.4.4
proxyarp
asyncmap 0
auth
crtscts
lock
hide-password
modem
debug
logfile /var/log/ppp/ppp.log
```

service xl2tpd restart

```
Starting xl2tpd:                                           [  OK  ]
```

При подключении с локальной машины ошибка "`VPN-соединение разорвано, поскольку служба VPN была остановлена`"

Логи на локальной машине `journalctl -f`:

```
ар 21 11:30:12 worked NetworkManager[1050]: <info>  [1521624612.8158] manager: (ppp0): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/17)
Мар 21 11:30:12 worked pppd[16880]: Using interface ppp0
Мар 21 11:30:12 worked NetworkManager[1050]: Using interface ppp0
Мар 21 11:30:12 worked pptp[16885]: nm-pptp-service-16873 log[main:pptp.c:350]: The synchronous pptp option is NOT activated
Мар 21 11:30:12 worked pppd[16880]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/7
Мар 21 11:30:12 worked NetworkManager[1050]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/7
Мар 21 11:30:12 worked NetworkManager[1050]: ** Message: nm-pptp-ppp-plugin: (nm_phasechange): status 5 / phase 'establish'
Мар 21 11:30:12 worked NetworkManager[1050]: <info>  [1521624612.8301] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Мар 21 11:30:12 worked NetworkManager[1050]: <info>  [1521624612.8307] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Мар 21 11:30:12 worked NetworkManager[1050]: nm-pptp-service-16873 warn[open_inetsock:pptp_callmgr.c:352]: connect: Connection refused
Мар 21 11:30:12 worked pptp[16888]: nm-pptp-service-16873 warn[open_inetsock:pptp_callmgr.c:352]: connect: Connection refused
Мар 21 11:30:12 worked NetworkManager[1050]: nm-pptp-service-16873 fatal[callmgr_main:pptp_callmgr.c:134]: Could not open control connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Мар 21 11:30:12 worked pptp[16888]: nm-pptp-service-16873 fatal[callmgr_main:pptp_callmgr.c:134]: Could not open control connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Мар 21 11:30:12 worked NetworkManager[1050]: nm-pptp-service-16873 fatal[open_callmgr:pptp.c:526]: Call manager exited with error 256
Мар 21 11:30:12 worked pptp[16885]: nm-pptp-service-16873 fatal[open_callmgr:pptp.c:526]: Call manager exited with error 256
Мар 21 11:30:12 worked NetworkManager[1050]: Modem hangup
Мар 21 11:30:12 worked NetworkManager[1050]: ** Message: nm-pptp-ppp-plugin: (nm_phasechange): status 11 / phase 'disconnect'
Мар 21 11:30:12 worked NetworkManager[1050]: Connection terminated.
Мар 21 11:30:12 worked pppd[16880]: Modem hangup
Мар 21 11:30:12 worked pppd[16880]: Connection terminated.
Мар 21 11:30:12 worked NetworkManager[1050]: <error> [1521624612.9594] platform-linux: do-change-link[18]: failure changing link: failure 19 (Нет такого устройства)
Мар 21 11:30:12 worked NetworkManager[1050]: ** Message: Terminated ppp daemon with PID 16880.
Мар 21 11:30:12 worked NetworkManager[1050]: <warn>  [1521624612.9594] device (ppp0): failed to disable userspace IPv6LL address handling
Мар 21 11:30:12 worked NetworkManager[1050]: <warn>  [1521624612.9622] vpn-connection[0x16cb590,dfee330c-5e7f-42a6-943a-8a5447b04cb2,"VPN-соединение 1",0]: VPN plugin: failed: connect-failed (1)
Мар 21 11:30:12 worked NetworkManager[1050]: <info>  [1521624612.9654] vpn-connection[0x16cb590,dfee330c-5e7f-42a6-943a-8a5447b04cb2,"VPN-соединение 1",0]: VPN service disappeared
Мар 21 11:30:12 worked NetworkManager[1050]: <info>  [1521624612.9697] devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Мар 21 11:30:12 worked NetworkManager[1050]: ** Message: nm-pptp-ppp-plugin: (nm_phasechange): status 1 / phase 'dead'
Мар 21 11:30:12 worked NetworkManager[1050]: ** Message: nm-pptp-ppp-plugin: (nm_exit_notify): cleaning up
Мар 21 11:30:12 worked pppd[16880]: Exit.
```

В чем может быть причина?

---

Подключиться из по Windows так же не удалось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вероятнее всего, ошибка вот в этой строчке:

> warn[open_inetsock:pptp_callmgr.c:352]: connect: Connection refused

то есть, клиент не может достучаться до порта сервера.

Таким образом, надо убедиться, что порт слушается на нужном интерфейсе `netstat -ln|grep xl2tpd` , если их несколько, а также убедиться, что его не закрывает файрволл.